# Different length of text columns

Tags: overleaf, two-column, templates

I'm using the template from [Oxford Bionformatics Journal](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-oxford-bioinformatics-journal-new-version/zjrmbrmtrytg) which divides the text in two columns. However, the first column is shorter than the second, notice that 1st column ends on the green line while 2nd column ends at the red line (at least it happens on the first page). This means that the text from the end of the first column ends up jumping to the start of the second leaving an empty gap at the bottom of the first column.

[image: GAP]

How can I make both columns to end on the reed line?

PS: Just to clarify, the sentence at the end of the first column continues at the start of the second, there is no line separation inserted.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If this happens on every page, it is probably deliberate and you should not attempt to "fix" it.  If it only occurs on one page, then it is probably content related.

Comment: It is happening in every page but I don't know what kind of words should I look at the class file in order to remove this gap.